# pausar navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html5, mediarecorder

Como faço para pausar a stream da câmara e microfone dentro do método `getUserMedia`?

Tenho o meu código assim:

```
navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true },
    function (MediaStream) {

        var video = document.querySelector('#videoRecord');
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(MediaStream);
        stream = MediaStream;
        var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(MediaStream);

// como pausar aqui o stream e depois iniciar novamente?

}, errorCallback);
```

Se eu usar

```
MediaStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
MediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
```

a luz da câmara desliga, mas não sei como voltar a colocar a stream outra vez, visto que faço tudo dentro da função `getUserMedia`, por isso não sei se faria sentido usar mais um `getUserMedia` dentro do que já existe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pausar câmera (MediaRecorder)

Experimente [**`MediaRecorder.pause()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/pause) e [**`MediaRecorder.resume()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/resume) pra restaurar, pode também usar o .pause no video (se tiver um player de video), segue um exemplo simples:

> **Detalhe importante**: `navigator.getUserMedia()` foi descontinuado, o ideal se usar é `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="play_pause">Play/Pause</button>

<script>  
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var playPause = document.getElementById('play_pause');

var stream, myMediaRecorder;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function (streamHandle) {
    player.srcObject = streamHandle;
    stream = streamHandle;
    myMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(streamHandle);
    myMediaRecorder.start();
});

playPause.onclick = function () {
    if (player.paused) {
       player.play();
       myMediaRecorder.resume();
    } else {
       myMediaRecorder.pause();
       player.pause();
    }
};
</script>
```

Exemplo [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mwL5ma87/2/)

---

### Parar liberar a câmera (MediaRecorder )

Para parar tudo é necessário usar:

- [**`MediaRecorder.stop()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/stop)
- [**`MediaStreamTrack.stop()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/stop)

Fora que é necessário terminar tudo que for possivel e para voltar é necessário (ao menos melhor) reiniciar tudo. Exemplo:

```
<video id="player" controls autoplay></video>
<button id="play_pause">Play/Stop</button>

<script>  
var player = document.getElementById('player');
var playPause = document.getElementById('play_pause');

var myStream, myMediaRecorder;

function gravar() {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function (streamHandle) {
        player.srcObject = streamHandle;
        myStream = streamHandle;
        myMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(streamHandle);
        myMediaRecorder.start();
    });
}

gravar(); //Auto inicia

playPause.onclick = function () {
    if (player.paused) {
        gravar();
    } else {
        myMediaRecorder.stop();
        player.pause();
        player.srcObject = null;

        var tracks = myStream.getTracks();

        tracks.forEach(function (track) {
            track.stop();
        });
    }
};
</script>
```

Exemplo [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x0gnrLt0/5/)

Comment: O meu problema é que o navegador indica que ainda há captura da webcam/audio mesmo quando se coloca em pausa, tal como acontece no seu exemplo também.

Comment: O que tenho é o seguinte: A pessoa grava um vídeo, quando clica stop eu mostro o video que ela gravou, e entretanto faço stop no MediaStream, se ela quiser gravar outra vez eu preciso de colocar no MediaStream a câmara e microfone novamente.

Comment: @ihavenokia então não é pausar né amigo? :) Mas tudo bem deu pra entender agora, vou faze um exemplo em alguns minutos te aviso

Comment: @ihavenokia criei um exemplo https://jsfiddle.net/x0gnrLt0/5/ pode testar, atualizei a resposta também.